# reading multiple csv.gz file into dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe, dask-delayed

I have multiple .csv.gz files which I'm trying to read into a dask dataframe, I was able to achive this using this code :

```
file_paths = glob.glob(file_pattern)
@delayed
def read_csv(file_paths):
    return dd.read_csv(file_paths, compression='gzip', blocksize=None,dtype=None)

dfs=[delayed(pd.read_csv)(fn) for fn in file_paths]
df = dd.from_delayed(dfs)
```

The problem is that when i tried converting the dask dataframe into pandas dataframe  using
`df=df.compute()`

I get the error message:
"EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file"
I would really appreciate any help with this

Comment: please check your file_paths: are the all indeed data files?

Comment: Thanks so much @mdurant, yes, all the files in the directory are .csv.gz files, each containing data.

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
file_path=r"C:\Users\John Doe\Downloads\checking gz"

dfs=[]
files=os.listdir(file_path)
for file in files:
    if '.gz' in file:
        df=dd.read_csv(file_path+'/'+file, compression='gzip',blocksize=None,error_bad_lines =False)
        dfs.append(df)
        print(df)
        
new_df=dd.concat(dfs)
pd_df=new_df.compute()
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Pawan,   yes, all the files in the directory are .csv.gz files, each containing data.  I have tried your code but i still get the same error.

Comment: Here is the error i get when i tried your code: EmptyDataError: An error occurred while calling the read_csv method registered to the pandas backend.
Original Message: No columns to parse from file

Comment: @maks, in that case, something is wrong with your files. I tried this on my laptop with some of my .gz files and it worked. i would suggest you try to load unzipped version of these files.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a dask high-level API like dask.dataframe inside a delayed function is not a good idea. In fact, your requirement should be a one-liner:

```
df = dd.read_csv(file_pattern, compression='gzip', blocksize=None)
```

and dask (or actually fsspec) will evaluate the pattern for you and make one partition per input file.